# React Native Firebase query snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-firebase

I want to get all posts all at once to limit requests to firebase server and increase speed. however I only want the `FlatList` to render 20 posts at a time from all the data saved in state for performance. Basically get all posts from firebase but render 20 at a time on device without making a request every 20 posts and then when user scrolls to the bottom more posts copied from local state to local state and now user sees 40 posts. Is that possible. Please help

This is how I am getting all posts how do make logic to limit posts locally with FlatList:

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  //getting all posts at once but want to limit them on device from two different states 
  // when user scrolls down the function adds 20 more posts
  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      var all = [];
      const unsubscribe = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp",'desc')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            all.push(doc.data());
          });
          setLoading(false);
        });
      setAllPosts(all);
      if(currentUser === null){
        unsubscribe()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached) prop from the FlatList component to call a function when the user reaches the end of the list. Then you have to enlarge your list in your state by 20.